# Using Lambda function to transform a set of string to a set of object

Tags: java, lambda, java-11

I am new in Java Lambda function, so the question probably is very simple.

I have an entity class and using Lombok:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Product {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;
  private String name;
  
  // getter & setters
  ...

}
```

Then, I got a `Set<String> data`, each element there represents the name of a `Product`. Now I would like to transform this `data` to `Set<Product> prodcts`. I tried two things:

1. I firstly tried to use constructor of `Product`:

```
Set<String> data = getData();

//Compiler error:reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that String conforms to Product
var products = data.stream().map(Product::new)
```

But I am not sure how to pass parameter to the constructor with this Lambda sytax & get also compiler error as shown in code.

2. Then, I tried directly calling the method:

```
Set<String> data = getData();

//Compiler error: Incompatible types: expected not void but compile-time declaration for the method reference has void return type
var products = data.stream().map(Product::setName)
```

But I get the compiler error `Incompatible types: expected not void but compile-time declaration for the method reference has void return type`.

What is the right way to do this transformation with Lambda function then?

Comment: You only have the name of the product. Do you want to create a new Product with only the `name` field set?

Comment: I will provide more information very soon

Comment: I updated my post with more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each element in the `data` Set, you can create a new Product and set its `name` and collect the resultant stream as a `Set<Product>`.

```
Set<Product> products = data.stream()
        .map(name -> {
            Product product = new Product();
            product.setName(name);
            return product;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If there is a constructor in the Product class which accepts the product name like,

```
public static class Product {
    int id;
    String name;
        
    public Product(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // getter & setters
}
```

Then you can simplify the *map* step with a method reference.

```
 Set<Product> products = data.stream()
        .map(Product::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

Outsourcing the `Product` creation into a `static` factory method

```
static public Product forName(String name) {
   Product = new Product();
   product.setName(name);
   return product;
}
```

allows for the usage of a method reference

```
 Set<Product> products = data.stream()
    .map(Product::forName)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```